# R data.table: Equivalent for SQL query

Tags: sql, r, group-by, count, data.table

I am looking for the data.table equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
select date, item, count(value) from dataset group by date, item
```

So far, what I've got is this:

```
dataset[, .SD, by = c("date", "item", "value")]
```

However, this is giving me the number of rows for each value. I'm not sure how to specify that I want the **number of values** for each item, for each date. How can I achieve this?

Comment: We could give you some answers, but the duplicate link already is written better tan we probably could do.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

`dataset[, .(Counts=.N), by = .(date,item)]`